# clojure: reductions: applying function n times, keeping intermediate results

Tags: clojure

### Problem Statement

Given n, x, f:
    I want output of the form:

```
[x, f(x), f(f(x)), f(f(f(x))), ..., f^{n-1}(x)]
```

### Existing solution

This can be done via reductions

```
(reductions
  (fn [state _] (f state))
  state
  (range n))
```

### Question

Is there a primitive that provides a shorter solution?

Comment: Wouldn't [iterate](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/iterate) do this? For your specific requirement, I think it would be `(take n (iterate f x))`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you want is [clojure.core/iterate](https://www.conj.io/store/v1/org.clojure/clojure/1.8.0/clj/clojure.core/iterate), which provides `f -> x -> [x, f(x), f^2(x), f^3(x), ...]` and [clojure.core/take](https://www.conj.io/store/v1/org.clojure/clojure/1.8.0/clj/clojure.core/take) which provides a way to slice the first `n` elements off of a sequence. `take` is lazy, as is `iterate` so there are no guarantees about side-effects.

Comment: Though both are lazy, neither `iterate` nor `take` are subject to chunking, so far as I can see from the source code. Nor can I see how you could implement `iterate` to *take advantage of parallelism*.

Comment: *thought* there would be a builtin for this. thanks!

Comment: FYI, I edited your answer to remove the discourse on chunking and laziness, because (1) it's not really related to the question as asked, and (2) I believe it's erroneous ((a) `iterate` isn't implemented as a chunked sequence, and (b) for arbitrary `f`, how would you compute `f^n(x)` without first computing `f^(n-1)(x)`?).  If you feel otherwise, feel free to revert.